Conditional formatting to highlight cells with dates specified in another cell, sometimes multiple dates?
I am trying to highlight cells in E5:K10 (a calender, the cells are formatted as dates) by referencing those dates (date only, sometimes multiple dates) in cells E16:E30.
Where I'm having trouble is getting excel to highlight multiple dates.
For example, E17 should say 8 - 10 (8/8/2024 - 8/10/2024) and the cells in E5:K10 that say 8, 9, and 10 should be highlighted.
I've gone through some of the similar posts, but I haven't been able to find anything that makes sense to me. Apologies if this has already been answered and thank you so much for your time!!
I've tried a few formulas, and none seem to work for me.
 =VLOOKUP(DAY(E5),$O$7:$O$11,1,FALSE)=DAY(E5)
under conditional formatting was what I started with.
I changed the way the dates were formatted in the calender and tried again with =COUNTIF($E$16:$E$30, E5) > 0  which worked until I needed to have multiple dates in one cell that highlights multiple dates in the calender.
Thats when I tried
=OR(
    ISNUMBER(MATCH(TEXT(E5, "d"), $E$16:$E$30, 0)),
    SUMPRODUCT(
        --ISNUMBER(SEARCH("-", $E$16:$E$30)),
        --(TEXT(E5, "d") >= VALUE(LEFT($E$16:$E$30, FIND("-", $E$16:$E$30)-1))),
        --(TEXT(E5, "d") <= VALUE(MID($E$16:$E$30, FIND("-", $E$16:$E$30)+2, LEN($E$16:$E$30)-FIND("-", $E$16:$E$30))))
    ) > 0
)

which is beyond my understanding and also did not work.

Does this work, tried to assume, how you data is laid out, as there is no sample in the OP: =LET(a, --TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(" | ",1,$E$16:$E$30)," - "," | ",1),OR(IFNA((E5>=DAY(TAKE(a,,1)))*(E5<=DAY(TAKE(a,,-1))),0)))

The solution is based on the context of the OP. So, if there are changes needed, it can be amended or modified, perhaps could try :


=LET(a, DAY(--TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(" | ",1,$E$16:$E$30)," - "," | ",1)),      
 OR((E5>=TAKE(a,,1))*(E5<=IFERROR(TAKE(a,,-1),TAKE(a,,1)))))



If you're on Windows, you could give this a try:
I have defined a couple of names in Names Manager - use of LAMBDA directly in conditional formatting is not available, but it is available via a defined name.
With E5 selected, I've defined highlight_on as
=OR(MAP(TOCOL(dates_to_highlight, 1), LAMBDA(range, AND(MONTH(!E5) = MONTH(TODAY()), DAY(!E5) >= --TEXTBEFORE(range, "-", , , , range), DAY(!E5) <= --TEXTAFTER(range, "-", , , , range)))))

I've also define the input range for dates as dates_to_highlight.
Formatted for ease of reading:
=OR(
    MAP(
        TOCOL(dates_to_highlight, 1),
        LAMBDA(range,
            AND(
                MONTH(!E5) = MONTH(TODAY()),
                DAY(!E5) >= --TEXTBEFORE(range, "-", , , , range),
                DAY(!E5) <= --TEXTAFTER(range, "-", , , , range)
            )
        )
    )
)

Method

For each cell (E5 etc.) in the calendar, iterate over the range dates_to_highlight via MAP, return TRUE if the date in the cell is within the current month and the within the range.

TOCOL is used to select the entries with data and ignore empty cells.



With E5 selected, define conditional formatting as
=highlight_on



This does not work under Mac - I have not figured out why yet.
